# Escuchar nuevos cambios desde la base de datos con laravel / pusher

Tags: php, javascript, laravel-5

Estoy utilizando este ejemplo que me brinda la pagina oficial de pusher, [Notificaciones web utilizando pusher con laravel](https://pusher.com/tutorials?q=laravel)

Esto lo conectare a una base de datos postgres y extraeré los datos desde allí como por ejemplo, usuario y mensaje... Necesito que la notificación me llegue cuando haya nuevos cambios en mi base de datos, que el pusher escuche y me envié la notificación de los nuevos cambios con el usuario y mensaje. He buscado bastante y no he encontrado un ejemplo.
Para la parte de front-end uso javascript y Back-end PHP.
Con el mas simple ejemplo de como podría hacerlo me basta para guiarme de ello.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te dejo el siguiente link:

[Vue Reactive](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/05/vue-js-reactivity/)

Lo he utilizado con django para hacer la página reactiva y mostrar cambios de una base de datos.

La otra opción es que utilices un cron que consulte directamente a una clase del back.